# How to filter rows by default in ag-grid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ag-grid

I have an ag-grid table that has a column 'status' in which some values are 'active' and some are 'inactive'.  I would like my table to only display rows that have an 'active' status by default.  Using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44916182/ag-grid-pre-setting-a-default-filter-for-the-grid) as a reference, I tried to set it like this using onFirstDataRendered:

```
  const onFirstDataRendered = (params: FirstDataRenderedEvent) => {
    const filter = params.api.getFilterInstance('status');
    if (filter) {
      filter.setModel({
        type: 'equal',
        filter: 'ACTIVE',
      });
      filter.onAnyFilterChanged();
    }
  };
```

but my code won't compile because it says I can't call onAnyFilterChanged because I "cannot invoke an object which is possibly undefined".  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue could be that the `type` should be `equals` not `equal`, as show in the documentation: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/filter-provided-simple/#simple-filter-options

If that doesn't fix the issue, then try using the [Filter API](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/filter-api/):

```
  const onFirstDataRendered = (params: FirstDataRenderedEvent) => {
    const filterModel = {
    status: {
        filterType: 'text',
        type: 'equals',
        filter: 'ACTIVE'
        },
    }
    params.api.setFilterModel(filterModel)
    
  };
```